# joining with code table with multiple codes in single cell

Tags: sql-server, join

So i have two tables with one being a code table like this:
**Codetable:**

```
Name |code  
Alex |Al  
Harry|Ha  
Sam  |Sm
```

**Data Table:**

```
ID|Game|Players  
1 |Map |AL Ha  
2 |Uno |As Da  
3 |Bro |Bd Ha  
3 |trio|Da Da Da Sm  
4 |pong|Al
```

I wanted to join the tables and get the data of the games with players that don't match, so the end result would be:

```
ID|Game|Players  
2 |Uno |As Da
```

I tried the following to first join the matching but it only gives me rows that are a straight match like Al=Al not like Al=Ha Al

```
select a.* from datatable a join codetable b on b.code like '%'+a.Players+'%'
```

Please let me know if you need additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your LIKE logic reversed and you need a LEFT JOIN to find those that do not match.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM DataTable a
LEFT JOIN CodeTable b on a.Players LIKE '%' + b.code + '%'
WHERE b.code IS NULL
```

This will also work.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM DataTable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM CodeTable b
   WHERE a.Players LIKE '%' + b.code + '%'
)
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1de03eaffbbf0b7d777a0e3d5e395dc6) of both.